# Django: select hot/most popular articles

Tags: python, django, orm

I've the following models

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    slug = UniqueSlugField(prepopulate_from='title', unique=True)
    favorited = models.ManyToManyField(to=User, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    ...

class Vote(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(to=Article)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name='voter')
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...
```

I use following line of code to get popular articles in descending order for a selected tag

`Vote.objects.filter(tags__in=[tag]).annotate(num_articles=Count('article')).order_by('-num_articles')`

How to build orm query to get popular articles by the following field of `Article.favorited` and based on `Vote` model?

Thanks,

Sultan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you get "popular articles" through the `Vote` model? When you run the query, you end up with a queryset of `Vote`s. Then, you must issue additional queries to get the `Article`s from that.

You should be using:

```
Article.objects.filter(tags=tag).annotate(vote_count=Count('vote')).order_by('-vote_count')
```

Then, you have a proper queryset of `Article`s and you're good to go.

If you want favorites, you would modify the above to use `user` instead of `vote`:

```
Article.objects.filter(tags=tag).annotate(favorite_count=Count('user')).order_by('-favorite_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join

```
Article.objects.filter(favorited__in=[...]).annotate(
        vc=models.Count('vote')).order_by('-vc')
```

Or normally faster(less joins), but more complex, and limited(no longer a QuerySet but not a big issue normally) sub-query version

```
qs = Article.objects.filter(favorited__in=[...])
top_votes = Vote.objects.filter(article__in=qs).values('article').annotate(
         vc=models.Count('pk')).values_list('article', 'vc').order_by('-vc')

# normally you may only want Top N
top_n_pks = tuple(pk for pk, vc in top_votes[:N])
tops = sorted(Article.objects.filter(pk__in=top_n_pks).order_by(),
         key=lambda x: top_n_pks.index(x.pk))
```